# C# Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am receiving the following error when testing to run a report:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal PerformCurrencyConversion(System.Decimal, System.Decimal, System.Decimal, System.String, System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here is my query:

```
List<BusinessPlanningElements> productSales = (from sale in ctn.ProductSales
    where sale.DateSold.Year == reportRequest.Year && sale.ProductID == t.ProductID
    group sale by sale.DateSold.Month into ds
    select new BusinessPlanningElements
    {
      Month = ds.Select(it => it.DateSold.Month).FirstOrDefault(),
      EURNumberOfUnitSold = ds.Where(it => it.EURSales.HasValue).Where(it => it.EURSales != 0).Count(),
      GBPNumberOfUnitSold = ds.Where(it => it.GBPSales.HasValue).Where(it => it.GBPSales != 0).Count(),
      USDNumberOfUnitSold = ds.Where(it => it.USDSales.HasValue).Where(it => it.USDSales != 0).Count(),
      EURCumulativeNumberOfUnitsSold = ctn.ProductSales.Where(it => it.EURSales.HasValue && it.EURSales != 0 && it.ProductID == t.ProductID && it.DateSold.Month <= ds.Key).Count(),
      GBPCumulativeNumberOfUnitsSold = ctn.ProductSales.Where(it => it.GBPSales.HasValue && it.GBPSales != 0 && it.ProductID == t.ProductID && it.DateSold.Month <= ds.Key).Count(),
      USDCumulativeNumberOfUnitsSold = ctn.ProductSales.Where(it => it.USDSales.HasValue && it.USDSales != 0 && it.ProductID == t.ProductID && it.DateSold.Month <= ds.Key).Count(),
      USDTotalSales = PerformCurrencyConversion(ds.Sum(it => it.USDSales.HasValue ? it.USDSales.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
      GBPTotalSales = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, ds.Sum(it => it.GBPSales.HasValue ? it.GBPSales.Value : 0), 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
      EURTotalSales = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, 0M, ds.Sum(it => it.EURSales.HasValue ? it.EURSales.Value : 0), reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
      USDCumulativeTotalSales = PerformCurrencyConversion(ctn.ProductSales.Sum(it => it.USDSales.HasValue && it.USDSales != 0 && it.ProductID == t.ProductID && it.DateSold.Month <= ds.Key ? it.USDSales.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
      GBPCumulativeTotalSales = PerformCurrencyConversion(ctn.ProductSales.Sum(it => it.GBPSales.HasValue && it.GBPSales != 0 && it.ProductID == t.ProductID && it.DateSold.Month <= ds.Key ? it.GBPSales.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
      EURCumulativeTotalSales = PerformCurrencyConversion(ctn.ProductSales.Sum(it => it.EURSales.HasValue && it.EURSales != 0 && it.ProductID == t.ProductID && it.DateSold.Month <= ds.Key ? it.EURSales.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
    }).ToList();
```

The PerformCurrencyConversion method pretty much gets a list of conversion rates, and converts the value to the currency which is specified by the user. It accepts parameters like so:

```
public decimal PerformCurrencyConversion(decimal usd, decimal gbp, decimal eur, string Currency, DateTime saleMonth)
{
    //Logic
}
```

I have used this method several times in the past throughout the codebase with no trouble or errors, e.g.

```
List<MonthlyProductSales> monthlyProductSales = (from sale in productSales
     orderby sale.DateSold descending
     group sale by new { sale.DateSold.Month, sale.Product.Name } into ds
     select new MonthlyProductSales
     {
         Name = ds.Select(it => it.Product.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
         Month = ds.Select(it => it.DateSold.Month).FirstOrDefault(),
         Year = ds.Select(it => it.DateSold.Year).FirstOrDefault(),
         USDNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.USDSales.HasValue).Where(it => it.USDSales != 0).Count(),
         GBPNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.GBPSales.HasValue).Where(it => it.GBPSales != 0).Count(),
         EURNumberItemsSold = ds.Where(it => it.EURSales.HasValue).Where(it => it.EURSales != 0).Count(),
         USDRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(ds.Sum(it => it.USDSales.HasValue ? it.USDSales.Value : 0), 0M, 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
         GBPRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, ds.Sum(it => it.GBPSales.HasValue ? it.GBPSales.Value : 0), 0M, reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
         EURRevenueTotal = PerformCurrencyConversion(0M, 0M, ds.Sum(it => it.EURSales.HasValue ? it.EURSales.Value : 0), reportRequest.Currency, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)),
     }).ToList();
```

Can anyone see what the difference is, or how I might get around this error?

Comment: Is the working code using Linq to Entities or Linq to Objects?

Comment: @AmiramKorach, it's in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the LINQ implementation.

In the first code sample, you are using **LINQ to Entities** (i.e., the LINQ implementation of Entity Framework). This implementation translates your LINQ into SQL which is eventually executed on the database.

In the 2nd code sample, you are using **LINQ to Objects** (i.e., in-memory collections). This implementation does not translate to SQL or another language, but simply creates a chain of actions that are executed on in-memory collections. Therefore, this implementation of LINQ can use .NET functions such as `PerformCurrencyConversion`.

So what you can do is first query your database using LINQ to Entities, and store the results in an array or list, and then do a LINQ to Objects query on that array or list -- and then you can use built-in .NET functions.